# What does "Cannot connect to host www.slack.com:443 ssl:None [Connection reset by peer]" from slack python api mean

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am using the python slack api to get channels historical messages.  I keep getting the error Cannot connect to host www.slack.com:443 ssl:None [Connection reset by peer] randomly.  The call I am using is

```
  response = client.conversations_history(
                channel=CHANNEL,
                limit=MESSAGES_PER_PAGE,
                cursor=response['response_metadata']['next_cursor']
            )
```

My only thought is that it could be a rate limiting issue but I'm not certain.  Any thoughts on possible problems would be very helpful.

Comment: This looks more like a "normal" network connection problem. You get an explicit API error when your exceed your rate limit. Do you get that error occasionally (then I would just retry) or always?

Comment: I was getting yesterday when I was making a lot of call but have not had the issue today.  I'm assuming at this point it was a network issue

Comment: @PDPDPDPD I have the same issue only if I try to run it by cronjob. On the other hand I can run it manually.

Comment: My issue just ended up going away one day. I'm not sure what ended up fixing it.